# UWP missing TextCompositionEventHandler

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I need to listen for `public event TextCompositionEventHandler TextInput;` (WPF), in UWP App page, but seems is missing. Can anyone give an suggestion ?
Bassically i need to catch a nfc card reader key, and check if key is valid and log in this user. In Wpf i was listening the the event described above.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking? How can a `TextInput` event relate to NCF card?

Comment: Actually it acts like a barcode reader (which acts like and keyboard).So i need to listen actually for keyboard input on a page.